multiple instance of an Image (texture)
When I load an Image in the image editor, most of the case I will use it in multiple places like in compositor , shader editor etc using 'image texture' nodes. In this node there's an alpha param where I can set for example to 'straight' or 'none'. But this setting is bound to the Image. So when I change it in the compositor, it will also change in other places like in the shader editor.


In my case , I want to have this 'alpha' parameter to stay independent for every nodes. For example in compositor maybe I want it to be 'straight' alpha while in the shader editor, I want it to be set to 'none'
Or possible to have 2 different instance of the same image so i can set different 'alpha' value ?

That little number 5 to the right, press that and it should make it a single user copy that you can adjust separately.

Thanks. solved.
